# Get position marker line-chart highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there any chance in the following example, get the exact position of the marker circle, with Highcharts?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'area',
    zoomType: 'x',
    panning: true,
    panKey: 'shift',
    scrollablePlotArea: {
        minWidth: 600
    }
},

title: {
    text: '2017 Tour de France Stage 8: Dole - Station des Rousses'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'An annotated chart in Highcharts'
},

annotations: [{
    labelOptions: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 15
    },
    labels: [{
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 27.98,
            y: 255
        },
        text: 'Arbois'
    }, {
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 45.5,
            y: 611
        },
        text: 'Montrond'
    }, {
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 63,
            y: 651
        },
        text: 'Mont-sur-Monnet'
    }, {
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 84,
            y: 789
        },
        x: -10,
        text: 'Bonlieu'
    }, {
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 129.5,
            y: 382
        },
        text: 'Chassal'
    }, {
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 159,
            y: 443
        },
        text: 'Saint-Claude'
    }]
}, {
    labels: [{
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 101.44,
            y: 1026
        },
        x: -30,
        text: 'Col de la Joux'
    }, {
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 138.5,
            y: 748
        },
        text: 'Côte de Viry'
    }, {
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 176.4,
            y: 1202
        },
        text: 'Montée de la Combe<br>de Laisia Les Molunes'
    }]
}, {
    labelOptions: {
        shape: 'connector',
        align: 'right',
        justify: false,
        crop: true,
        style: {
            fontSize: '0.8em',
            textOutline: '1px white'
        }
    },
    labels: [{
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 96.2,
            y: 783
        },
        text: '6.1 km climb<br>4.6% on avg.'
    }, {
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 134.5,
            y: 540
        },
        text: '7.6 km climb<br>5.2% on avg.'
    }, {
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 172.2,
            y: 925
        },
        text: '11.7 km climb<br>6.4% on avg.'
    }]
}],

xAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: '{value} km'
    },
    minRange: 5,
    title: {
        text: 'Distance'
    }
},

yAxis: {
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: false,
    maxPadding: 0.35,
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value} m'
    }
},

tooltip: {
    headerFormat: 'Distance: {point.x:.1f} km<br>',
    pointFormat: '{point.y} m a. s. l.',
    shared: true
},

legend: {
    enabled: false
},

series: [{
    data: elevationData,
    lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    name: 'Elevation',
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    threshold: null
}]
```

});

What I want is that when a user clicks on the chart, get the marker circle position

It is for use with the annotations plugin, get the coordinates of that point or circle, and create a note right there

**To make it clear, this point**:

[image]

[Line chart](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/annotations)

Comment: If you use the code found here: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/YQ6Bt/ you can find the position of the mouse, all you need to do is to add a click event to capture the position at that time.

Comment: I already know that, and it's like I have it now, but I do not want to be able to put the annotation anywhere on the screen, otherwise, exactly where the little circle is

Comment: You can use this: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/Lv05sjhq/ too busy to do it properly right now, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem
using the data array, and with the following code

```
events:{
            click: function(e){
                var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
                    y = elevationData[x.toFixed(1)*10][1];
                this.addAnnotation({
                    xValue: x,
                    yValue: y,
                    allowDragX: false,
                    allowDragY: false,
                    title:{
                            text: "Hola"
                    } ,
                    shape: 'text'
                });
                //this.redraw();
                this.redrawAnnotations();
                console.log(this.annotations);
            }
        }
```